# Is it haram to draw a pixel art for games that includes eyes but no face or body?

Tags: halal-haram

I make a 2D physics based games, and i have doubts if making pixel arts in a rectangle with eyes without body is permissible or prohibited in Islam like the image below.[image: like this image]